# Heatmap with binary outcome variables on a continous x-axis - is it possible?

Tags: r, ggplot2, binary, heatmap

Made up data

```
Years (row): 0.5, 0.5, 1.1, 2.0

A: (column 1): 1, 0, 1, 1

B: (column 2): 0, 0, 1, 1

C: (column 3): 0 ,1 ,0, 0
```

I have tried to make a heatmap for my data in R, where I would like to have the results of the different markers (A, B, C) on the Y-axis, and on the x-axis, I would like to have the Years (>200 data).

I have tried many different ways and combinations but somehow I cannot make it work.

I am using R, I have tried using `ggplot`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(Data,aes(x=Years,y=markers,fill=factor(Positive/Negative)))+geom_tile()
```

I know this is not correct, but I simply don't know how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?
You need to melt your data so that you can use the Years and classes as labels and your values as fill-values:

```r
library(data.table)
df <- fread(
'Years      A    B   C
0.19       1    0   0   
0.21       0    1   1   
1.00       0    0   1
2.25       1    0   1'
)

library(tidyverse)

df %>% melt(id.vars = 'Years') %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = as.factor(Years), y = as.factor(variable), 
             fill = as.factor(value))) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('black', 'white')) +
  labs(x = 'year', y = 'marker',fill = 'result')
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I have been trying to make. Thank you very much, I will try and see if I can make it work.